# I want to Rotate 3 different images on different location in 360 degree in swift 4 using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, uibezierpath, xcode9.3

I want to Rotate  3 different images on different location in 360 degree in swift 4 using UIBezierPath. [i am able to move single image like this in image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxSPv.jpg) with this code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.midY), radius: 120, startAngle: 0, endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi)*2, clockwise: true)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position");
    animation.duration = 5
    animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
    animation.path = circlePath.cgPath

    let moon = UIImageView()
    moon.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:40, height:40);
    moon.image = UIImage(named: "moon.png")
    view.addSubview(moon)
    moon.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)



 }

}
```

and I want to rotate 3 different images on different Angle and Position like this.[i want to rotate all 3 different images like in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1rVE.png)

Anyone here who can update my code according to the image above I want Thank You in Advance Cheers! :) .

Comment: Few days ago I gave an answer for the same thing. You need circle boundary points please have a look at [Rotate a ImageView around a pivot point in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919926/rotate-a-imageview-around-a-pivot-point-in-ios/49920188#49920188).

Comment: @TheTiger Thanks , but as i said i am able to rotate  one image around 360 degree, and now i want to rotate 2 more images start rotating from different angles and positions. Can you please modify my swift code accordingly.

Comment: So just change the `startAngle` and `endAngle` for other views I mean increase the both angles.

Comment: Would you please mind to accept the answer or give a feedback if there is any issue?

Comment: @TheTiger Thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your code and its working. I made a function to rotate a `imageView`.

```
func startMovingAView(startAnlge: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat) {

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.midY), radius: 120, startAngle: startAnlge, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true)

        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position");
        animation.duration = 5
        animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
        animation.path = circlePath.cgPath

        let moon = UIImageView()
        moon.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:40, height:40);
        moon.image = UIImage(named: "moon.png")
        view.addSubview(moon)
        moon.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
 }
```

And here is the angles what I pass for each `imageView`:

```
/// For first imageView
var startAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
var endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(Double.pi) * 2.0
startMovingAView(startAnlge: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle)

/// For second imageView   
startAngle = CGFloat(Double.pi/2.0)
endAngle = CGFloat(Double.pi) * 2.5
startMovingAView(startAnlge: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle)

/// For third imageView  
startAngle = CGFloat(Double.pi)
endAngle = CGFloat(Double.pi) * 3.0
startMovingAView(startAnlge: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle)
```

We just need to find the angles with same difference so that in `5` seconds duration the `imageView` have to travel the same distance so all objects moves with constant and same speed.